# Pass model from a view to a controller (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, lambda, asp.net-mvc-5

When passing the model from my view to my controller, the data is all null. I was able to successfully pass it using an `ActionLink` but I don't think that is the best way; for security reasons (I do not want sensitive data in the querystring).

**My models**

```
public class DashboardModel
{
    // Dasboard quick numbers
    public int TotalUsers { get; set; }
    public int TotalUnauthUsers { get; set; }
    public int GamesPlayed { get; set; }
    public int AssociatedGroups { get; set; }
    public int TotalGroups { get; set; }

    // Dashboard table
    public IEnumerable<ManageUserData> UnauthUsers { get; set; }

}

public class ManageUserData
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int AlternateId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> InvestigatorGroups { get; set; }
    public string Institution { get; set; }

    // User status
    public bool AccountLocked { get; set; }
    public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
}
```

**Snippet of my view**

```
@model TestGame.ViewModels.DashboardModel

@foreach (var user in Model.UnauthUsers)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@user.UserName</td>
        <td>@user.AlternateId</td>
        <td>@user.Email</td>
        <td>@user.Role</td>
        <td>
            @if (!user.EmailConfirmed)
            {
                <div class="text-warning">Unconfirmed Email</div>
            }
            @if (user.AccountLocked)
            {
                <div class="text-danger">Account Locked</div>
            }

        </td>
        <td>

            @if (user.AccountLocked || !user.EmailConfirmed)
            {

                using (Html.BeginForm("Manage", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => user.UserName)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => user.Email)

                    <input type="submit" value="Manage" />
```

Comment: Only content within the form submitted will be sent to the server - it will not regenerate the entire model for you, unless all of the data from the model is defined as an input within the form (textbox, hidden field, drop down).

Comment: I understand that, I am only passing `UserName` and `Email` as a test to see if those two fields in the model are not null which it isn't. I believe the issue might be that there I am trying to pass fields from a model within a model

Comment: See my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Does your action handle HTTP POST command?  In other words, do you have [HttpPost] attribute added to your action?

Comment: There is a lot here, the question is basically too broad. Things you need to consider: `return View()` is basically a call which executes razor code as c# in that same scope and then *writes a string to the response stream*. That is the end of razor's action. After that it is just an html page built from a string. In order to get anything back to the scope of the server, information must be sent again as a string. Either in the form of a request body or in a querystring. They are both strings. When this request is sent to the server, the url naming determines the controller and actionresult.

Comment: These names are then sent to the routing mechanism and use reflection to create an instance of the controller and invoke the actionresult. The accepting parameter of the actionresult will have matching properties populated using the modelbinder. How you achieve what you want based on this process is up to you. There are many ways, including ajax which you haven't mentioned.

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop like that to generate form controls for items in a collection. Look at the html your generating - the `name` attributes of your hidden controls - they have no relationship at all to the model your binding to. But what is your issue with security? The user can easily inspect the page source and see all the `UserName` and `Email` properties anyway so its hardly 'sensitive'.

Comment: You're probably getting null values because the names of the parameters don't match.  For example: your '@Html.HiddenFor(x => user.UserName)' is probably generating a field with a name like Dashboard.Username (because of the parent DashboardModel model) and it's not matching the action ManageUserData model property of 'Username'.  You might be able to get around this by making your form a partial view that has a model of type ManageUserData OR, instead of using @Html.HiddenFor, you could do: <input type="hidden" value="@user.UserName"/>, but like stephen said, this won't increase security.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure the path starts with the object being posted back; what you have will work great if the action being posted to  (HttpPost Admin/Manage action) takes an object of type User; if it takes an object of the model type, change your form to the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.UnAuthUsers.Count; i++)

 using (Html.BeginForm("Manage", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UnAuthUsers[i].UserName)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UnAuthUsers[i].Email)

                    <input type="submit" value="Manage" />
```

Creating a reference from the model (being x) will do the trick.

EDIT: Based on comments, add two properties to your model:

```
public class DashboardModel
{
   public string SelectedUserName { get; set; }
   public string SelectedEmail { get; set; }
}
```

In your form, render a hidden for for that name; I've had trouble using HiddenFor, so I've in the past used the hidden directly:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Manage", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
{
   <input type="hidden" name="@Html.NameFor(i => i.SelectedUserName)" value="@Model.UnauthUsers[i].UserName" />
   <input type="hidden" name="@Html.NameFor(i => i.SelectedEmail)" .. />
```

And upon submitting the form, the user from that form will be posted back via the model, via these new properties.

Comment: The problem with this is that I only want the username, email, etc.. to be passed for the selected user. What I have is a table with users and to the right there is a manage button. I want the manage button to pass a model to the controller for that selected user

Comment: And my action does take a parameter of type user `public ActionResult Manage(ManageUserData model)`

Comment: See my edit- i included another alternative - names don't have to be unique, so you can use the same properties as the name of the form entry; only the submitted form will send the hidden field value back to the server.